# Can this ATMega328-PU ATMEL microchip be used instead of MCP3008

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

I wanted to follow [this tutorial](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-raspberry-pi-moisture-sensor-to-monitor-your-plants--mac-52875) as a first project.

I've got all the parts I need, but I could not purchase the [chip](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) that was linked in the article.

So I found another [chip](http://hobbycomponents.com/ics/315-atmega328-pu-atmel-microcontroller-chip-programmed-with-arduino-bootloader?search_query=8-Channel%2010-Bit%20A%2FD&results=9) that sound similar (To a complete beginner) .

My question is, will I be able to use the chip I brought, in place of the one suggested in the article or am I trying something thats impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but your tutorial breaks down because you are not following it.

The ATMEGA is actually a microcontroller. It requires more attention to setup the hardware as well it requires programming. If you are a complete bigger and want to follow the tutorial, then this might not be the approach you want to take. That's not to say you can't do it, it's just slightly more complicated to get working.

The MCP3008 is an external 10bit ADC. It is not as complicated to get working than a microcontroller.

If you can find a 10bit external ADC, you should be able to follow your tutorial pretty well.

Comment: Would this work? http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/pic16f676-n36bx

Comment: That's another microcontroller. So it's the same answer as above. Search for "external adc". The keyword is external

Answer (score 2):

The Microchip IC you refer to is a ADC, the Atmel device is an MCU which has integrated ADC in it. In theory you can use the ATMega's ADC + MUX to get the readings you need and send them over simulating the original ADC.

That is of course creating more work for yourself for no good reason. You can buy the Microchip [here](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=MCP3004).

Comment: I assume DAC was a typo...

Comment: @alexan_e Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

No. Indeed they're quite different: [MCP3008](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) is an A/D converter and [ATMega328-PU](http://hobbycomponents.com/ics/315-atmega328-pu-atmel-microcontroller-chip-programmed-with-arduino-bootloader?search_query=8-Channel%2010-Bit%20A%2FD&results=9) is a microcontroller (which has a built-in A/D converter).

Answer (score 1):

Well, atmel chip which you link to is a microcontroller, which roughly means that it is a microprocessor with peripherial circuits etched in the same piece of silicon, however that MCP you link is a A/D converter which simply means that it converts analog signal to discrete, digital interpretation of it. **These are completely different kinds of devices, and they can't be swapped between**
If you want to learn and understand mechanics behind A/D converters, you can try and make your own in FPGA, **or you could use a microcontroller (like atmega328 you just linked to) to make use of its built-in ADC and communicate with your master processor with serial interface**.
That can be done, but requires lot of coding and attention to wiring your device. If there's anything that needs to be cleared or explained I'd be more than glad to help you